# android, how to vertical center align children items of the RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, vertical-alignment, android-relativelayout

Having a RelativeLayout, which has left and right two children containers,  the right side might be higher/or short height, and the left container has a few children items some of them may dynamically visible or not.

something like left side has vertically AAA, bbb, CCC etc. They should vertically distribute the available space. So when bbb is hidden, the remaining AAA, CCC will have more space above and below.

```
-------------------  ------------------------
|  AAA            |  |                      |
|                 |  |                      |
|  bbb            |  |      Right side      |
|                 |  |                      |
|  CCC            |  |                      |
-------------------  ------------------------

bbb is visibility = "gone"

-------------------  ------------------------
|                 |  |                      |
|   AAA           |  |                      |
|                 |  |      Right side      |
|   CCC           |  |                      |
|                 |  |                      |
-------------------  ------------------------
```

change to vertical LinearLayout for wraping the left side, and adding spacer above AAA and below CCC will work if the left side is shorter than right side, but does not work if the left side is higher than right side.

when left has more content and height is higher than right side, it should be like:

```
-------------------  ========================
|  AAA            |  |----------------------|
|                 |  |                      |
|  ddd            |  |                      |
|  bbb            |  |      Right side      |
|  eee               |                      |
|                 |  |                      |
|  CCC            |  |----------------------|
-------------------  ========================
```

Having a layout like below, but it does not adjust when some of the children view in left side are hidden, like:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <!-- "@id/asset_container" is at right side, has a lot children views, not showing here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/asset_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"

            tools:visibility="visible"

            tools:layout_width="360dp"
            tools:layout_height="120dp"
            tools:background="#ff0000"
        >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- left side -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/asset_container"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            tools:text="ad title a little bit long, for testing what the title will look like wrap in second line"
            />

        <!-- "@id/wrapper" has a lot children views, not showing here -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/asset_container"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_above="@+id/text"

            tools:visibility="gone"

            android:background="#ffff00"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text text"
                />
            <!-- -->
            <!-- -->
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/asset_container"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="test"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/icon"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/text"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/option"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            tools:text="very long long long name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/optin"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/asset_container"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it working, but hope there is better way.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <!-- left side -->
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/right_side_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <!-- item AAA --->
            <!-- item ddd --->
            <!-- item bbb --->
            <!-- item eee --->
            <!-- item ccc --->


            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
   <LinearLayout >

   <!-- right side -->
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/right_side_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            >
        <!-- children items -->
   </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```